# Cannot Get Spyder To Use In-Line Plots With IPython Interpreter

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

Disclaimer: I'm new to Python + Spyder for scientific computing.

**EDIT**: Here are my tool versions:

```
Python 2.7.4
IPython 0.13.2
Spyder 2.1.13.1
```

I'm having an issue getting Spyder to plot figure in-line.

Here is my source:

```
def plot_stuff2():
    x = np.linspace(0, 3, 20)
    y = np.linspace(0, 9, 20)
    plt.plot(x, y)       # line plot    
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r*')  # dot plot
    plt.show()
```

When running in Console with an IPython interpreter, the figure shows in a new window and blocks the program. I would prefer to have the figure created in-line and have the program continue.

I can get IPython to display the plot in-line if I "Start a new IPython kernel" and use the newly created "IPython client". However then I cannot use the Object inspector on the Console as a source. I would prefer to just have an in-line plot with the IPython interpreter.

My configuration for Interpreter is "Excecute in current Python or IPython interpreter" and I have the IPython console selected.

Comment: Have you checked under Preferences->IPython console->Graphics if the backend is set to inline. Furthermore, make sure you're using the newest Spyder version. I had some similar problems with Python 3.3 a while ago (I'm using 2.7 without problems).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I do not have an IPython console or graphics menu in Preferences. It looks like I'm not running the latest Spyder version. I will update and see what happens.

Comment: #Dietrich: If you comment was an answer I'd upvote it. I'm fairly new to Spyder/iPython as well, and after updating, I'd get a blank "not responding" figure when trying to plot (but worked fine with just a python console). Your suggestion to check preferences pointed me to the right direction. Default seemed to be not loading the right libraries.